# Image downloading in python error handling

Tags: python, image, http, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I have text file containing images and I have a directory where I wanted to save my images.

```
import os
import urllib
import sys


def normalize(url):
   url = url.split("/")[-1]
   return url.split("\n")[0]

def main():
   out_dir = "Workspace/cnf/img"

    with open('cnf/image_flower.txt') as url_array:
    for url in url_array:
        try:
           urllib.urlretrieve(url, os.path.join(out_dir, normalize(url)))
         except Exception as e :
            print "Exception|",e,"|",url

print("Images Downloaded")
```

main()

I am getting the images.But I am facing the following issues
1.I want to catch all the http error codes and print it like page not found and all kind of error.which my code is not able to print.
2.I have around 1,00,000 urls.So my code is taking a lot of time.

Could you please suggest me a better way to handle it

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code seems fine. However you might want to check your indentation in your 'except' line code. Python programming is based on indentation so it might not work.

`try:
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, os.path.join(out_dir, normalize(url)))
 except Exception as e :
    print "Exception: ",e," at ",url`

2. If you have around 100,000 urls to download images, I guess it should take sometimes depend on how large your images are.

Comment: My code is working fine.What I want is to catch if there is http error.like page not found.which this try and exception is not able to handle.

Comment: Try to print out the error status code in your Exception 
`print e.code`
If it returns 404 then it is page not found error.
then you can handle it using If  
`if e.code == 404:
        # do stuff..  
 else:`
Also checkout urllib2.HTTPError if it still doesn't work for you.